# Convert decimal fractions like 12.125 to hexadecimal? (By hand)

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal

I know the by-hand method to convert a decimal number to hexadecimal.

Method : Divide decimal number by 16. Store remainder aside (and convert to hex)
Next, keep dividing the quotient by 16 and storing the remainder aside (while converting it to hex) until the quotient is 0. Then read the hex numbers from the bottom to the top in order to obtain the hex number of the decimal.

Now, in a file my teacher provided for extra problems to help prepare for our exam, she put questions of conversions including Hex to Decimal and Decimal to Hex (like convert the numbers 15048, 299028 and 762513415 from decimal to hex).

**However, the two last numbers were 0.2 and 12.125...**

**How do you convert this type of decimal to hexadecimal?** Is the process the same? I have never seen any conversions from decimal to hex using similar examples above.

*** PS - I would have to convert using my pen and paper, not using coding as a way to convert.

Comment: Hint - it's just like in decimal, except with a different base. e.g. 0.21h is eqivalent to 2 * 1/16 + 1 * 1/(16*16).

Comment: From a deleted answer: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/64392.html

Answer (score 1):

For converting decimal fractional part to hexadecimal , multiply the fractional part by 16 and write its hexadecimal equivalent , then continue multiplying the remaining fractional part by 16 till we get 0 as hexadecimal equivalent.

In your case:

a) 0.2 * 16 = 3.2

so we take 3's hexadecimal equivalent

then

0.2 * 16 = 3.2 ,

since its repeating we will stop here

the answer is 0.3333

which is its hexadecimal equivalent.

b)12.125,

for the integer part

we will divide by 16

12/16 = 0

here the remainder is 12

whose hexadecimal equivalent is C .

For the fractional part

we multiply by 16

0.125*16 = 2.000

0.00*16 = 0.00

since we got zero we stop it here

so the hexadecimal equivalent part of 12.125 is

C.2 .

Hope it cleared some of your doubts.